# when using @weakify get error unexpected '@' in the program

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

When using @weakify, I get error unexpected '@' in the program. Am I missing some .h files?
I already imported ReactiveCocoa.h. Is there any thing I should do ?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        _isSeperateFill = YES;
        _isBorderStroke = NO;
        _isSeperatedStroke = YES;

        _contentWidth = 0;

        @weakify(self);
        [RACObserve(self, dataVO) subscribeNext:^(TableDataVO* dataVO){
            if( dataVO ){
                NSString* indexKey = [[dataVO.tableDataDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:0];

                _keys = [dataVO.tableDataDictionary allKeys];
                @strongify(self);
                _rows = [[self.dataVO.tableDataDictionary objectForKey:indexKey] count];
                @strongify(self);
                [self.styleVO setTableHeaderLineHorizontalMargin:self.styleVO.tableWidth / [_keys count]];
            }
        }];

        @weakify(self);
        [RACObserve(self, styleVO) subscribeNext:^(TableStyleVO* styleVO){
            if( styleVO ){
                styleVO.tableHeaderLineHorizontalMargin = styleVO.tableWidth / [_keys count] / 2;
            }
        }];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Are you importing `ReactiveCocoa.h` into the file where you’re trying to use `@weakify` (or into your .pch)?

Comment: Yes, I imported the ReactiveCocoa.h and I can use RAC and RACObserve macros

Comment: Can you post the lines that come before `@weakify`? Sometimes an error on one line is actually a mistake on the line before.

Comment: snapshot url https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1966791/3929043/176300a0-2417-11e4-9e87-6ccabc8b4227.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@weakify`, `@strongify` and friends are part of [libextobjc](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc), not [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) proper.

Try adding this line (per @chakming's comment):

`#import "ReactiveCocoa/RACEXTScope.h"`

Or for pre-2.3.1 ReactiveCocoa (my original answer), use:

`#import <ReactiveCocoa/EXTScope.h>`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed to import that .h file

Comment: for reactivecocoa 2.3.1, it should be `#import "ReactiveCocoa/RACEXTScope.h"`

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly related to the question at hand, but I thought I'd comment and mention that your use and placement of weakify and strongify is incorrect. The correct version would be...

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        _isSeperateFill = YES;
        _isBorderStroke = NO;
        _isSeperatedStroke = YES;

        _contentWidth = 0;

        @weakify(self);
        [RACObserve(self, dataVO) subscribeNext:^(TableDataVO* dataVO){
            @strongify(self);
            if( dataVO ){
                NSString* indexKey = [[dataVO.tableDataDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:0];
                _keys = [dataVO.tableDataDictionary allKeys];
                _rows = [[self.dataVO.tableDataDictionary objectForKey:indexKey] count];
                [self.styleVO setTableHeaderLineHorizontalMargin:self.styleVO.tableWidth / [_keys count]];
            }
        }];

        [RACObserve(self, styleVO) subscribeNext:^(TableStyleVO* styleVO){
            if( styleVO ){
                styleVO.tableHeaderLineHorizontalMargin = styleVO.tableWidth / [_keys count] / 2;
            }
        }];

    }
    return self;
}
```

As you can see above, you only need to use weakify once. Once defined it's defined for the entire scope.

Similarly, strongify is only needed once in a block. Further, it's needed at the top of the block so you recapture the weak reference as a strong reference as soon as possible.

By the time it's used in your example it's possible that the captured weak reference to self could have gone out of scope.